# How to output data from a multi-dimensional array group index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get the values from one of the the array parent group index or 
first level '1006' by using the foreach loop, but not having much luck. I could 
use a little help here getting the child or sub data out of the given array group.

```
Array ( 
    [1004] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [od_id] => 1004 [pd_id] => 42 [pd_name] => Red Hat ) 
        [1] => Array ( [od_id] => 1004 [pd_id] => 33 [pd_name] => Green Hat ) 
        [2] => Array ( [od_id] => 1004 [pd_id] => 44 [pd_name] => Blue Hat )
     ) 
    [1006] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [od_id] => 1006 [pd_id] => 33 [pd_name] => Green Hat ) 
        [1] => Array ( [od_id] => 1006 [pd_id] => 44 [pd_name] => Blue Hat )
        [2] => Array ( [od_id] => 1006 [pd_id] => 41 [pd_name] => Pink Hat )
     ) 
    [1007] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [od_id] => 1007 [pd_id] => 29 [pd_name] => Purple Hat ) 
        [1] => Array ( [od_id] => 1007 [pd_id] => 24 [pd_name] => Orange Hat ) 
        [2] => Array ( [od_id] => 1007 [pd_id] => 44 [pd_name] => Blue Hat ) 
    )
)
```

Comment: I would rather to have the results assign to a new array like <pre>$od_id[] .= 'the array results'</pre> instead of a string.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like below:-

```
<?php
$s=array ( "1004" => array (     " 0" => array ( "od_id" => 1004 ,"pd_id"=> 42 ,"pd_name" => 'Red Hat' ) ,"1" => array ( "od_id" => 1004, "pd_id" => 33, "pd_name" => 'Green Hat' ),"2" => array ( "od_id" => 1004,"pd_id" => 44,"pd_name" => 'Blue Hat' )));
foreach($s as $a=>$b)
{
foreach($b as $c=>$d)
{
foreach($d as $e=>$f){
echo $f;
}
echo'<br>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood your problem, but if you just want to read all values from a given index, you could do something like the following:

```
foreach ($array[1006] as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        echo "$k: $v ; ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Which will print:

```
od_id: 1006 ; pd_id: 33 ; pd_name: Green Hat ;
od_id: 1006 ; pd_id: 44 ; pd_name: Blue Hat ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_multisort() function 
for more detail [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)